# Prove: functions with bounded derivatives are Lipschitz continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, proof-verification

I'm a 1st year mathematics student, and in my analysis class I'm having trouble with proving the following:

Let
$M > 0$, $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$ and $|f'(x)| \leqslant M$ for all $x \in (a, b)$

Prove:
$\forall x, y \in [a, b]: |f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant M|x - y|$

So far, I think I proved it, but I'm not sure if there are any mistakes in this proof:

$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$, so according to the mean value theorem, $\forall x, y \in [a, b]$ with $x \neq y: \exists c \in (a, b): |\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y}| = |f'(c)| \leqslant M$
Now it follows that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant M|x - y|$

Could you please tell me if this proof is correct, and if not, what is the correct way to prove this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's correct but it shuld be $|f'(c)|$ not $f'(c)$.

Comment: @Rubertos Oh sorry my fault. Just edited it. I'm only wondering if I did not make a mistake with the open interval. Because I know this is correct if $|f'(x)| \leqslant M$ for al $x \in [a, b]$

Comment: Oh right you made a mistake. It should be $\exists c\in (a,b)$. I didn't look it carefully. Except this part, other things looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Community wiki answer to remove the question from the Unanswered queue:*

Yes, your proof is correct (after the edits you made following the discussion in comments)